# Avoid overlapping views based on frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiview

I have the following Graphview:

[image]

It's a simple UIView and it contains two other types of UIViews:

1. The Vertex
2. The Edge between the Vertices

I'm currently "spawning" the vertices randomly on the view (code following) and connecting the vertices based on their center point:

```
/// Layout our subviews
override public func layoutSubviews() {
    nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height * 0.1)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    addSubview(nameLabel)

    print(self.graph.vertexCount)

    for index in 0 ..< self.graph.vertexCount{
        // Draw Vertexes
        let vertexName = self.graph.vertexAtIndex(index)
        let vertex:Vertex = Vertex(name: vertexName)

        let VALID_WIDTH = self.bounds.size.width - vertex.bounds.size.width
        let VALID_HEIGHT = self.bounds.size.height - vertex.bounds.size.height

        let x = CGFloat(CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: VALID_WIDTH))
        let y = CGFloat(CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: VALID_HEIGHT))

        vertex.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: vertex.frame.size.width, height: vertex.frame.size.height)
        self.addSubview(vertex)
        self.vertices.append(vertex)
    }

    // Draw Edges
    for vertexIndex in 0 ..< self.graph.vertexCount{
        let edges = self.graph.edgesForIndex(vertexIndex)
        for var edge:Edge in edges{
            let from:Vertex = vertices[edge.u]
            let to:Vertex = vertices[edge.v]

            let edgeView = EdgeView(frame: self.frame, from: from, to: to, edge: edge)
            self.addSubview(edgeView)
            self.edgesViews.append(edgeView)
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is now that sometimes (because its spawning randomly) the vertices & edges can overlap each other e.g.:

[image]

Is there a way to solve my issue?

Comment: Check Apple's `CGGeometry` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cggeometry), it has methods to determine the intersection of `CGRects`. You could test each new vertex to see if it intersects a previous vertex.

Comment: Can you maybe elloborate how you would do that? What about the edges?

Comment: My thought was you would iterate over the array of vertices and check if the new vertex intersected with any one of the existing vertices, if so just spawn a new vertex. However, if you want to prevent both vertex and edge overlaps, then randomly adding vertices seems like a bad idea. I think you need to construct your graph with your constraints in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used now the following function. Basically it takes a random rect and checks it against **every** element in an Array containing `CGRect`. If any element intersects it creates a new random `CGRect` and tries again.

The performance is `O(n)`

```
func getNewRectIfIntersect(rect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var newRect:CGRect = CGRect()

    var doesNotIntersect = false

    while doesNotIntersect == false {

        let x = CGFloat(CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: CGFloat(VALID_WIDTH)))
        let y = CGFloat(CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: CGFloat(VALID_HEIGHT)))

        newRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 50)

        let matches = rectarray.filter { $0.intersects(newRect) }

        print("there were \(matches.count) matches")

        if matches.count == 0 {
            // do some things
            doesNotIntersect = true
        } else {
            doesNotIntersect = false
        }
    }


    return newRect
}
```